# Django error on contact form - join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object,

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to create a contact form for my school project, but get this error and have no idea what it means.

I'm creating this form based off another form that works fine.

I've tried googling and couldn't make sense of what the problem is.

Can anybody shed any light please?

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\01\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\ntpath.py", line 91, in join
    for p in map(os.fspath, paths):

During handling of the above exception (expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not dict), another exception occurred:
  File "C:\Users\01\Desktop\TUD Y2\Sem4\bsp\store\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\01\Desktop\TUD Y2\Sem4\bsp\store\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\01\Desktop\TUD Y2\Sem4\bsp\store\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\01\Desktop\TUD Y2\Sem4\bsp\store\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\01\Desktop\TUD Y2\Sem4\Project\bsp\store\contact\views.py", line 11, in get
    return render("contact.html", context)
  File "C:\Users\01\Desktop\TUD Y2\Sem4\bsp\store\env\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\01\Desktop\TUD Y2\Sem4\bsp\store\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
    template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\01\Desktop\TUD Y2\Sem4\bsp\store\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 15, in get_template
    return engine.get_template(template_name)
  File "C:\Users\01\Desktop\TUD Y2\Sem4\bsp\store\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 34, in get_template
    return Template(self.engine.get_template(template_name), self)
  File "C:\Users\01\Desktop\TUD Y2\Sem4\bsp\store\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line 143, in get_template
    template, origin = self.find_template(template_name)
  File "C:\Users\01\Desktop\TUD Y2\Sem4\bsp\store\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line 125, in find_template
    template = loader.get_template(name, skip=skip)
  File "C:\Users\01\Desktop\TUD Y2\Sem4\bsp\store\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loaders\base.py", line 18, in get_template
    for origin in self.get_template_sources(template_name):
  File "C:\Users\01\Desktop\TUD Y2\Sem4\bsp\store\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loaders\filesystem.py", line 36, in get_template_sources
    name = safe_join(template_dir, template_name)
  File "C:\Users\01\Desktop\TUD Y2\Sem4\bsp\store\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\_os.py", line 17, in safe_join
    final_path = abspath(join(base, *paths))
  File "c:\users\01\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\ntpath.py", line 117, in join
    genericpath._check_arg_types('join', path, *paths)
  File "c:\users\01\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\genericpath.py", line 152, in _check_arg_types
    raise TypeError(f'{funcname}() argument must be str, bytes, or '
```

admin.py

```
class ContactAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'subject']
    list_per_page = 20

admin.site.register(Contact, ContactAdmin)
```

forms.py

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    firstname=forms.CharField()
    lastname=forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    subject = forms.Textarea()
```

models.py

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    firstname=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    lastname=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email=models.EmailField(null=False)
    subject=models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.lastname}, {self.firstname}, {self.email}'
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', ContactView.as_view(), name='contact'),
]
```

views.py

```
class ContactView(View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = ContactForm()
        context = {'form': form}
        return render("contact.html", context)
        
    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = ContactForm(self.request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid():
            firstname = form.cleaned_data.get('firstname')
            lastname = form.cleaned_data.get('lastname')
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            subject= form.cleaned_data.get('subject')
            contact = Contact()
            contact.firstname = firstname
            contact.lastname = lastname 
            contact.email = email
            contact.subject = subject
            contact.save()
            messages.info(self.request, "Your message has been received.")
            return render('thanks_contact.html')
```

project URLs

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('',include('shop.urls')),
    path('search/',include('search_app.urls')),
    path('cart/', include('cart.urls')),
    path('contact/', include('contact.urls')),
    path('order/',include('order.urls')),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    path('vouchers/',include('vouchers.urls',namespace='vouchers'))
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

contact.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block title %}
    Contact 
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <div class = "container">
    <h2>Contact</h2>
    <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <button type='submit' class="btn btn-primary my-3">Submit</button> 
    </form>
    </div>
        
{% endblock content%}
```

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please update the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: Yeah sorry, it was saying question has too much code. I've included full traceback

Comment: I think in the urls.py you want `ContactView.as_view()`, not just `ContactView`.

Comment: I tried that, but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's the changes you need to add

in the urls:

```
    from django.urls import path
    from .views import ContactView


    urlpatterns = [
        path('', ContactView.as_view(), name='contact'), #add as_view()
    ]
```

in the views :

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from .forms import ContactForm
    from django.views import View
    from .models import Contact
    from django.contrib import messages



    class ContactView(View):
        def get(self,request, *args, **kwargs): #add request
            form = ContactForm()
            context = {'form': form}
            return render(request,"contact.html", context) #add request 
        pass
        def post(self,request, *args, **kwargs): #add request
            form = ContactForm(self.request.POST) 
            if form.is_valid():
                firstname = form.cleaned_data.get('firstname')
                lastname = form.cleaned_data.get('lastname')
                email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
                subject= form.cleaned_data.get('subject')
                contact = Contact()
                contact.firstname = firstname
                contact.lastname = lastname 
                contact.email = email
                contact.subject = subject
                contact.save()
                messages.info(self.request, "Your message has been received.")
                context = {'form':form} #add context
                return render(request,'thanks_contact.html',context) #add request and context
```

in the forms :

```
    from django import forms

    class ContactForm(forms.Form):
        firstname=forms.CharField()
        lastname=forms.CharField()
        email = forms.EmailField()
        subject = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea) # pass textarea as widget
```

Comment: i  re constructed this part of your code, and verified it, did you change all the commented lines i added?

Comment: ok ,so what does the error say now? because the - join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, was caused by missing 'request'

Comment: whats forma/contact.html, tried that and forms/

Comment: My bad, that just MY path of html files, stick with Yours so it can work ,i,ll correct them in the answer

Comment: OK THE FORM RENDERS BUT THE SUBMIT GIVES name 'context' is not defined

Comment: aaahhh got it removed last context, thank you so much

Comment: ow ok ! happens a lot, happy to help